# How do I get real random in CMD?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, random-number-generator, random

I have some script which every PC in network download and execute, and the task is NOT to run script simultaneously. So, I used simple pseudo-random for timeout like

```
TIMEOUT /T 2%random:~0,2%
```

But as I found out it is not random enough since some PCs still execute script simultaneously.
So I decided to make random a bit more random and come up with next code, yet untested

```
SET /A rnd_time=3%random:~0,2%-1%random:~0,2%
TIMEOUT /T %rnd_time%
```

But I am not sure if it will be random enough. So, may be there is a way to get, well, not real random, but pseudorandom which would be random enough for my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: What do you need the number for?  Would a GUID be better suited for the task?

Comment: True randomness will still produce matching times. I don't think a random is the right solution, rather a controlled pseudo random will allow you to avoid conflicts. Also, if you're using a scheduled task there's already a built in function for randomizing start times.

Comment: I need number for timeout for script execution. For example: 01. All PC start and download script. 02. One by one all PC execute script with random delay time.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is %random% in Windows time based and how to get a real random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59823766/995714). But the better solution is to just throw cmd away and use powershell instead